# Big Theta complexity for simple algorithm

Tags: pseudocode, big-o

I have the following code and have to determine the big theta complexity

```
for i =1 to n do
    for j = 1 to n do
        k=j
        while k<= n do
           k = k*3
        end while
    end for
end for
```

It's easy to see that the first two for-loops run n times each, but the while loop is throwing my off. The first time it runs log3(n) times, but after that i can't really tell. 
Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 1):

Let T be the run time. It is clear T is Ω(n<sup>2</sup>). We can use [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to expand ln n! to get
T = ∑<sub>i</sub> ∑<sub>j</sub>  ⌈lg<sub>3</sub>(n/j)⌉ = n * O(∑<sub>j</sub> ln n - ln j + 1) = n * O(n ln n - ln n! + n) = n * O(n ln n - (n ln n - n + O(ln n)) + n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Thus T = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)

Answer (score 0):

Solution without using heavy-weight math:

Turn the problem on its head: instead of thinking about the first time the inner loop runs, think about the last time: it runs only once. In fact, the innermost loop *runs only once* for most values of `j`.

It runs  once when j > n/3, that is, for 2n/3 values of j
It runs twice when n/9 < j <= n/3, that is, for 2n/9  values of j
It runs 3 times when n/27 < j <= n/9, that is, for 2n/27  values of j
It runs 4 times when n/81 < j <= n/27, that is, for 2n/81  values of j
...

The total number of times the innermost loop runs is going to be

1 * 2n/3 + 2 * 2n/9 + 3 * 2n/27 + 4 * 2n/81 + ... 
= 2n(1/3 + 2/9 + 3/27 + ... )
< 2n Sum[k/3^k, for k=1 to infinity]

It's easy to see that the series `Sum[k/3^k]` converges (ratio test). Therefore the j-loop runs in O(n) time, and the entire thing in O(n²) time.